# Reverse engineer StackExchange winter bash

Tags: javascript, websites

I'm curious if it's possible to reverse engineer the hat positioning and control of the StackExchange winter bash.

They offer the "show controls" checkbox, but it's still all mouse-based; when you try to get as large a hat and as far off as possible, it simply starts shrinking, and it's difficult to go back.  Any idea if it's possible to get around that?  (The controls only seem to change the alignment, and are not too helpful.)

Comment: Isn't it all Javascript then?

Comment: @Jongware, yes, it is; however, someone who's looked at it, says it's pretty obfuscated, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270943/221016

Comment: @cnst deobfuscate a js snippet ? are u sure isnt a stepover ?

Comment: It's basically changing svg image, but I haven't tried to change the values manually (e.g. increase the scale manually), but it's worth to try. Have you tried anything so far?